# CAKEPHP Confirming on Submit

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have a submit button in my form like this :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

and I want to embed variables that are part of the input form.

For example, I want to embed a variable that is input here `$this->Form->input('user_id');`.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I currently have this `onsubmit` as part of the options array, but it throws errors when I try to embed variables.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Shift', array(
    'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Creating shift for '$id' on ");'
)); ?>
```

Now making an edit to this question.  So the Javascript solution worked fine.  Issue now is that I want the alert box to display the user's name, which is what is displayed in the dropbox.  However, the HTML tags contain the user's ids.  Here is the HTML

```
<div class="input select required">
    <label for="my_user_id">User</label>
    <select name="data[Shift][user_id]" id="my_user_id" required="required">
    <option value="1">john doe</option>
    <option value="2">john johnson</option>
```

Is there a way to access the value between the `<option>` tags using Javascript?

Comment: It would be better if you start another question if you got an answer on the first one. Your edit has nothing to do with the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Shift', array(
    'onsubmit' => "return confirm(\"Creating shift for '$id' on \");"
));
?>
```

Another option is to use [$this->Form->postLink()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink) and set $confirmMessage parameter if it is a simple state shift form.

Comment: Simple. Solid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery

```
echo $this->Form->create('Shift', array('id' => 'myform'));
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('id' => 'my_user_id', 'type'=>'text'));
```

After the form:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
      alert("Creating shift for " + $("#my_user_id").val());
    });
});
');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked very well.  I have added onto my question, with a followup.